# If $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are relations on a set S with $R_{1};R_{2}=R_{2};R_{1}$. Then $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are bijective maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

For the surjectivity part, I showed that if $(a,b)\in I$ then $(a,c)\in R_{1}$ and $(c,b)\in R_{1}$ and $(a,c)\in R_{2}$ and $(c,b)\in R_{2}$ for some $c\in S$. Now for arbituary $(x,y)\in R_{1}$ we have $(x,z)\in I$ which implies that $(y,z)\in R_{2}$. But also $(y,z)\in R_{1}$, so $R_{1}$ is surjective. Similar argument for $R_{2}$

And for Injectivity, I've tried to show that if $aR_{1};R_{2}c$ and $bR_{2};R_{1}c$, then $a=b$ but I am not entirely sure what $a=b$ means in this context. Do I have to show that there is an equivalence relation containing (a,b)?

edit: $R_{1};R_{2}$ is a composition of two relations and $I=R_{1};R_{2}$

Comment: What does $R_1;R_2$ stand for? And what is I?

Comment: $R_{1};R_{2}$ is a composition of two relations and $I=R_{1};R_{2}$

Comment: a = b means a and b are the same element of S.  How do you get from (x,y) in R1 to (x,z) in I?  What is z?  At first reading I am left with the impression of incoherence.

Comment: Here is my guess about what this question is asking: Suppose that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are binary relations on a set $S$, and $I$ is the equality relation (or "identity" relation) on $S$. Further suppose that the compositions $R_1;R_2$ and $R_2;R_1$ both equal $I$. Show that $R_1$ is the graph of a bijection and $R_2$ is the graph of its inverse.

Comment: Sei-- do you agree with Keith's version above? [you didn't mention the compositions were both I]

Comment: It turns out that $I$ is indeed an identity relation and I will post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Claim 1: $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are maps.

Suppose $(a,b) \in R_{1}$. Now $(b,c) \in R_{2}$ for some $c \in S$. But then $c=a$ 
since $(a,c) \in R_{1} \circ R_{2}=I$. So for arbituary $x \in S$, if $(x,y) \in R_{1}$ then $(y,x) \in R_{2}$.

Now, suppose $(x,y) \in R_{1} \wedge (x,z) \in R_{1}$. Then $(y,x) \in R_{2}$ so $(y,z) \in R_{2} \circ R_{1}=I \implies y=z$

So $R_{1}$ is a map. Same line of argument for $R_{2}$

Claim 2: $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are injective.

Suppose $(x,y) \in R_{1} \wedge (x^*,y) \in R_{1}$. But then $(y,x^*) \in R_{2}$
so $(x,x^*) \in R_{1} \circ R_{2} \iff x=x^*$. Same argument for $R_{2}$

Claim 3: $R_{1}$ is sujective (and hence $R_{2}$).

Let $s \in S$ arbitrary. Then $(s,l) \in R_{2} \iff (l,s) \in R_{1}$. Hence $R_{1}$ is sujective.

Above imply that both $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are bijective maps